# JHipster inheritance

Tags: inheritance, intellij-idea, jhipster, class-diagram, jdl

I'm currently trying to code my UML-diagram scheme in JDL-Studio, but inheritance isn't supported apparently. Answers from different platforms didn't help.

Let's say I want the class Fashion to inherit from Department. Is there a way to bypass the inheritance issue?

[image: UML class diagram]

I aim to import the finished JDL-Studio code to my IntelliJ project.

I included some relation types, so you can see the syntax of JDL-studio.

```
relationship OneToOne {
    Location{country} to Country
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Department{location} to Location
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Job{task(title)} to Task{job}
}
```

Comment: You'll have to code it manually by modifying generated code or tables depending on which inheritance mapping strategy you decide to use. So your first step is to decide about this strategy based on your business requirements. See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance for an introduction

Answer (score 3):

As Gaël Marziou commented, you have to implement it manually. I just want to repeat it to see an answer on your question on stackoverflow - by no means to take his credits (he's undoubtedly great!!).

For coding the generated source further, I just want to point at Side-by-Side-coding to be able to update your code with jhipster in the future. There is a good practice example and [detailed explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo) from David Steiman (xetys) on youtube, along with inheritance.